# How to treat two or more arrays at separate addresses as one in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am working with a microcontroller and I can only statically allocate an array up to a certain size at a fixed address in flash ram. If the required size exceeds the maximum size, I'll also need to allocate a second array sized to the difference at another fixed address.

```
unsigned char buffer[CONF_BUFF_SIZE] __attribute__ ((section ("SRAM_BANK2")));  // allocated on free SRAM at 0x1000
#ifdef CONF_BUFF_SIZE > BUFF_MAX
       unsigned char buffer[CONF_BUFF_SIZE] __attribute__ ((section ("SRAM_BANK4"))); // allocated on 0xF000
#endif
// lots of yuck and muck with indexing and switching addresses
```

I would like to convert the code over to modern C++ (c++2x). I would also like to iterate and index over the two buffers as if it were one contiguous array without explicitly calculating the index and switching arrays. How do I achieve this in idiomatic modern C++?

buffer[1000] = 0xFE;  // modifying memory in "buffer2"

Comment: "*I can iterate and index over the two buffers as one contiguous array*" What do you mean by "contiguous" here? A proper `contiguous_range` cannot happen across two non-contiguous memory locations, as contiguous ranges must be... contiguous.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just replace "as" with "as if it were." I don't know that getting hung up on semantics is necessary in this case. Anyway, my suggestion is to use a class to hide the details and provide an API that treats the two "as if it were" one.

Comment: Create a wrapper class that aggregates the two buffers and provides an appropriate `operator[]` overload.

Comment: Do you have any indication that this is possible, at all?

Comment: As mentioned above, wrapper class, so SplitArray>T> s  that maps s[ ix ] to the proper buffer[ bx ][ ix - bx_element_0 ]

Comment: @G.M. Yes, it's exactly what I am looking for. I presume aggregate doesn't do any copying.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understood. The two buffers exist in far apart and don't run into each other.

Comment: What is `BUFF_MAX` determined by? i.e. why can't you simply declare `unsigned char buffer[CONF_BUFF_SIZE];`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts BUFF_MAX is the maximum size a flash block size. If CONF_BUFF_SIZE is greater than BUFF_MAX, you will need to allocate the rest of it in another block.

Comment: Just be careful if you take addresses *(&x[i]+1)` may not equal x[i+1]. Stick with indexes.

Comment: @ATL_DEV since it's trivial to extend the solution from two to N arrays, do you have any use for viewing more than two, or do you prefer a solution that only deals with exactly two?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Doesn't matter to me, but it should be straightforward to extend it if needed.

Comment: @ATL_DEV How do you specify the placement in memory in this environmet? I'm just curious to see how it looks if I I'm going to come up with a better alternative to my current answer. Is it just cast from address to `unsigned char*`?

Comment: GCC has a pragma to get the address from an ld file:  ```unsigned char buffer[CONF_BUFF_SIZE] __attribute__ ((section ("SRAM_BANK2")));```

Comment: @ATL_DEV Ok, so you don't specify the addresses directly in code, but use different sections? ...and you use chunks in different sections that you want to join?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Precisely.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Ok, do you need random access to elements in the joined buffers or is it ok if you can iterate over them?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a `std::deque`...

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Sorry I didn't see your last message. I do prefer random access generators.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't understand how it's like deque?  Do you mean how deque is implemented.

Comment: @ATL_DEV They are iterators, not generators, but I get your point. You can get both iterators covering the joined range and seemingly  random access via the subscript operator. My answer deal with the iterator bit. The other two deals with random access to the elements. With some tinkering, you can combine them.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Yes, like `std::deque` is implemented.

Answer (score 6):

If your functions that uses the buffers can use iterators, you could join two `std::span`s:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <span>

auto glue = {std::span<unsigned char>(buffer),
             std::span<unsigned char>(buffer2)};
auto joined = glue | std::views::join;

for (auto& ch : joined) {
    ch = ...; // assign
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1zd8G893r)

Note that you don't get random access iterators, so this is suitable for reading/writing big chunks of data, but you can't access a specific `unsigned char` in the joined buffers without actually iterating from `begin()` - or by manually doing the calculation in which buffer the `unsigned char` that you want to access is placed.

---

A class for combining supporting iterators and something that can be *perceived* as random access could look like as outlined below.

At the core, it's one `std::array` of `std::span`s and one of the `ranges::join_view`s over the `span`s (like shown above).

The `operator[]` overloads do a runtime calculation (inside the `get` member function) to do the lookup in the correct buffer - so a lookup for an element in buffer 1000 will take longer than the lookup for an element in buffer 1. As long as you don't try accesses out of bounds, it doesn't do bounds checking, but if you *do* try OOB access, the buffer index calculation will end with `std::terminate()`. You can replace that with throwing an exception if you'd rather want that.

I've tried to make the buffer index calculation in `get` readable by presenting the fold expression like an `if`/`else if`/`else` chain, but it's not easy to present it so it is easy to read.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <utility>

template <class T, std::size_t... Ss>
class glued_view {
    using IS = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ss)>;
    using span_array =
        std::array<std::span<T, std::dynamic_extent>, sizeof...(Ss)>;

    static constexpr auto view_builder(span_array& sps) noexcept {
        return sps | std::views::join;
    }

public:
    constexpr glued_view(T (&... arrays)[Ss]) noexcept
        : spans{arrays...}, view(view_builder(spans)) {}

    constexpr glued_view& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
        std::copy_n(il.begin(), std::min(size(), il.size()), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return (... + Ss); }

    // semi-random access
    constexpr T& operator[](std::size_t index) noexcept {
        return get(index, IS{});
    }
    constexpr const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const noexcept {
        return get(index, IS{});
    }

    // iterators
    constexpr auto begin() { return view.begin(); }
    constexpr auto end() { return view.end(); }

private:
    span_array spans;
    decltype(view_builder(spans)) view;

    // lookup helper
    template <std::size_t... I>
    constexpr T& get(std::size_t idx,
                     std::index_sequence<I...>) const noexcept {
        T* p;
        (void)(((
        /*if*/      ((idx < Ss)                     // correct buffer?
        /*then*/    && (p = &spans[I][idx]))        // then store pointer
        /*else...*/ || ((void)(idx -= Ss), false))  // else subtract size of current
        /*...if*/   || ...) // next if              // and try next buffer
        /*else*/    || (std::terminate(), false));  // OOB => terminate
        return *p;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W8ra4jvG5)

A simpler `get` would just loop instead of making a big boolean expression out of it:

```cpp
    constexpr T& get(std::size_t idx) const noexcept {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ss); ++i) {
            if(idx < spans[i].size()) return spans[i][idx];
            idx -= spans[i].size();
        }
        std::terminate();
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/78zqP37vW)

Answer (score 3):

A solution would be to make a view class something like this :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
class arrays_view
{
public:
    arrays_view(std::array<int,N1>& arr1, std::array<int,N2>& arr2) :
        m_arr1{arr1},
        m_arr2{arr2}
    {
    }

    int& operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        assert( index < m_arr1.size() + m_arr2.size() );
        if ( index < m_arr1.size() ) 
        {
            return m_arr1[index];
        }
        index -= m_arr1.size();
        return m_arr2[index];
    }

private:
    std::array<int,N1>& m_arr1;
    std::array<int,N2>& m_arr2;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int,3> values1{1,2,3};
    std::array<int,4> values2{4,5,6,7};
    arrays_view view{values1,values2};

    assert(view[0] == 1);
    assert(view[2] == 3);
    assert(view[3] == 4);
    assert(view[6] == 7);

    view[2] = -1;
    assert(view[2] == -1);
}
```

Comment: Technically you only need one method `constexpr int& operator[](std::size_t index) const;` because `arrays_view` does not have ownership of `m_arr1` and `m_arr2`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Me bad I even wanted to leave constexpr out of it (for now) to keep the example simple. Because I think there should be a separate constexpr const_view

Comment: In your edit, the method returning `int&` can be `const` qualified, that was the point I was originally trying to make.

Comment: @PepijnKramer  We're dealing with resource restricted hardware, so a const_view would be appropriate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I could see how this could be extended for an arbitrary number of arrays, but calculating the offsets can get fairly complex.

Comment: What I mean with a "const view" is that it will not allow you to change any values, only read them. For read only access that would mean that all offsets known at compile time can be calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive class template to support arbitrarily many buffers:

```cpp
#include <span>

template <class T, std::size_t... Sizes>
class span_view {};

template <class T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t... Sizes>
class span_view<T, Size, Sizes...> {
  std::span<T, Size> first;
  [[no_unique_address]] span_view<T, Sizes...> rest;

 public:
  span_view(std::span<T, Size> first, std::span<T, Sizes>... rest)
      : first(first), rest(rest...) {}

  T &operator[](std::size_t index) const {
    if constexpr (requires { rest[index - Size]; }) {
      if (index >= Size) {
        return rest[index - Size];
      }
    }

    return first[index];
  }
};

template <class T, std::size_t... N>
span_view(T (&...arrays)[N]) -> span_view<T, N...>;

template <class T, std::size_t... N>
auto make_const_span_view(T (&...arrays)[N]) -> span_view<const T, N...> {
  return {arrays...};
}
```

and example usage:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

#define BUFF_MAX 256
#define CONF_BUFF_SIZE 700

extern unsigned char buffer[BUFF_MAX];
extern unsigned char buffer2[BUFF_MAX];
extern unsigned char buffer3[CONF_BUFF_SIZE - BUFF_MAX * 2];

int main() {
  const span_view view{
      buffer,
      buffer2,
      buffer3,
  };

  view[202] = 2;
  view[303] = 3;
  view[606] = 6;

  const auto const_view = make_const_span_view(buffer, buffer2, buffer3);

  // const_view[404] = 4;  // error

  std::printf("%d", const_view[202] + const_view[303] + const_view[606]);
}
```

Testing on Clang and GCC, compiler optimizations are able to completely elide the `span_view` and refer directly to the buffers for this example code: https://godbolt.org/z/4ezMrqYvd

Comment: This is very nice! Here's a [possible simplification](https://godbolt.org/z/hqYcrz8c7) using a `std::tuple<std::span<T, Sizes>...>` to store the `span`s and without using recursion for the lookup.

Comment: @TedLyngmo finally had a chance to look at your link. I like the fold expression but I think I'll keep my recursive approach for this answer. Feel free to post that as another answer if you want though, it's certainly a viable approach.